# Компилятор почему-то не видит класс

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Я решил написать очень простенький "язык программирования" на *С++* для того, чтобы научиться работать со строками и классами.

Проблема вот в чём: когда я начал реализовывать переменные, я завёл новый класс со своими методами и свойствами. В классе "компилятора" я завёл массив map для хранения значений переменных, в качестве значения указал класс с описанием свойств и методов переменных. Не компилирует, ошибка:

```
include/Compiler.h|44|error: ‘Variables’ was not declared in this scope|.
```

Заголовок класса компилятора:

```
#ifndef COMPILER_H
#define COMPILER_H

#include "Variables.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>


using namespace std;

class Compiler
{
public:
int compile(); //компилятор
int cleaner(); //чистка файла
string gettingOfCode = ""; //способ получения кода
string filename = ""; //имя файла

Compiler(); //конструктор
virtual ~Compiler(); //деструктор
private:
//операторы
string operator1 = "PRINT";
string operator2 = "INPUT";
string operator3 = "ALERT";
string operator4 = "END";
string operator5 = "EL";
string operator6 = "CYCLE";
string operator7 = "EC";
string operator8 = "=";
/*
string operator9 = "+";
string operator10 = "-";
string operator11 = "*";
string operator12 = "/";
string operator13 = "IF";
string operator14 = "FILE";
*/
//работа с переменными
map<string, Variables> vars;
//
string comment = "//";
//значения переменных
int intBuf;
string stringBuf;
    //получение кода
string line;
vector<string>code;
void getCode();
int getFileCode();
int getKeyboardCode();
};

#endif // COMPILER_H
```

Заголовок класса работы с переменными:

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H

#include "Compiler.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Variables
{
public:
void setType(string);
string getType();
void setInteger(int);
int getInteger();
void setString(string);
string getString();
void setBool(bool);
bool getBool();
Variables();
virtual ~Variables();
protected:
private:
string varType;
int integerVal;
string lineVal;
bool boolVal;
};

#endif // VARIABLES_H
```

Если нужно, могу скинуть код других файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы в начале файла `Variables.h` пишете `#include "Compiler.h"`, а в начале `Compiler.h` — `#include "Variables.h"`. Уберите это инклюды из хедера и переместите в соответствующий .cpp-файл. Для ссылок друг на друга используйте предварительную декларацию наподобие

```
class Variables;
```

Comment: в смысле? в какой .cpp?

Comment: @NEzyaka: Соответствующий. У вас, надеюсь, в дополнение к каждому header'у есть соответствующий .cpp-файл с имплементацией?

Comment: да, конечно, а в какой именно?

Comment: @NEzyaka: В соответствующий. Из Variables.h в Variables.cpp. Какой файл _соответствует_ Compiler.h, остаётся вам в качестве упражнения.

Comment: это у меня уже есть, а так, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

У вас заголовочные файлы ссылаются друг на друга, в файле Variables.h подключение Compiler.h явно лишнее.

Comment: спасибо огромное, всё работает!